# Redirect apache to http requests to https except for when request is a POST?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have setup my apache2 configuration to redirect http requests to https. This works fine however I want to change it so that it only does this if the request is not a POST request.

Here is my current configuration:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
>
> RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https:// %{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

How can I change this configration so that it only redirects when the request is not a POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new `RewriteCond` line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https:// %{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```